# Displaying Progress of Long Running Save Process in SilverLight out of browser application

Tags: silverlight, progress-bar, savefiledialog

I've got a little SilverLight Out-of-Browser app that captures a series of images from a WebCam to LocalStorage. I then wish to export them out of LocalStorage via a Zip file into a location specified by the user.

So far, so trivial if everything happens on the main UI thread, with no additional methods.

However, for a large enough series of files, the creation of the zip file takes considerable time, so I'd like to have this happen on a background worker thread or similar, and report the progress to the user.

My problem is this:

If I try and do everything on the main UI thread, the ProgressBar doesn't update until the save is complete.

Trying to open the SaveFileDialog on a Background Worker won't work as it's a background thread, and would also be considered "Not User Initiated".

No matter how I pass the Stream that was opened in the SaveFileDialog to the method as part of the delegate for the background worker, it's always changed to `CanWrite == false` and I can't use it any more.

Does anyone have a simple example of saving a large file and reporting progress in SilverLight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim any specific knowledge of file handling in Silverlight, but here's the pattern I'd use for a long task on a worker thread in a WPF application. It seems to work ok in a quick test Silverlight project.

I would avoid trying to pass streams between threads. Instead, work out the set of parameters your background task needs and create an object to pass them to your thread. Let the background thread open the files. So if you need a folder to search for files to zip up and an output location to put the zip into, you might declare:

```
class TaskStartupInfo
{
    public string SourceFolder { get; set; }
    public string TargetFile { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of this class, and pass it into your background task:

```
private void startTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskStartupInfo tsi = new TaskStartupInfo()
    {
        SourceFolder = @"C:\Some\Folder\",
        TargetFile = @"C:\AnotherFolder\data.zip" 
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => longRunningProcess(tsi));
}
```

In your case, the paths can come from a SaveFileDialog you run on the main UI thread - since that thread will not be tied up with running the bulk of the work. Your `longRunningProcess()` method can then take the data and work with it:

```
private void longRunningProcess(object o)
{
    TaskStartupInfo tsi = o as TaskStartupInfo;

    int taskLength = calculateTaskLength()

    // open any files required

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { progressBar1.Value = 0; progressBar1.Maximum = taskLength; });

    for (int i = 0; i < taskLength; i++ )
    {
        doSomethingSlow();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => progressBar1.Value += 1);
    }

    // close / dispose files
}
```

Note how any attempt to access a UI object (`progressBar1` in this case) is done by using the Dispatcher object to run a delegate. This dispatcher deals with the issue of ensuring that the UI objects are only ever updated by the UI thread. That should ensure your progress bar updates after each fragment of the task is completed.

---

**Edit:** Based on the OP's comments, and having done some further digging, I see that Silverlight's security sandbox imposes restrictions on file access that aren't imposed in a desktop WPF application.

Writing to the filesystem outside of Isolated Storage does indeed require that the Silverlight app be run elevated. This can be configured as part of the project properties - there is a checkbox for "Enable running out of browser" on the Silverlight tab of the properties, and once that's enabled the "Out of browser settings" button below it allows you to open a further options dialog which has the "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser" checkbox. I've not tested it, but that option certainly sounds like you wouldn't get elevated trust inside the browser - so it probably makes sense to check for security errors in your code and handle the lower trust situation if it occurs.

Once that setting is enabled, you seem to be able to use normal streams to access files in the user's Libraries, but not elsewhere on the filesystem. By default the `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` classes return streams as implied in the question, but both of them do allow you access to the file name rather than the stream if you wish. When opening a file the filename is hidden under

```
myOpenFileDialog.File.FullName
```

and for saving you appear to be able to use

```
mySaveFileDialog.SafeFileName
```

instead.

So the following code can work in an elevated Out-of-Browser app:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() != true)
    {
        return;
    }

    TaskStartupInfo tsi = new TaskStartupInfo()
    {
        SourceFolder = @"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Information",
        TargetFile = sfd.SafeFileName
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => longRunningProcess(tsi));
}

private void longRunningProcess(object o)
{
    TaskStartupInfo tsi = o as TaskStartupInfo;

    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tsi.SourceFolder);

    int taskLength = files.Count();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { progressBar1.Value = 0; progressBar1.Maximum = taskLength; });

    using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(tsi.TargetFile))
    {
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            fs.WriteLine(file);
            doSomethingSlow();
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => progressBar1.Value += 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And that gives you both file access and a correctly updated progress bar for the processing of the files in the backgrond.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to look at running the SL app with Elevated Permissions. The issue is that the SL `SaveFileDialog` doesn't provide a path I can access, only the stream that the user specified - otherwise I wouldn't even be using the ZIP (which is effectively just a container for all the images) I'd just write the files directly to the path. I believe that if I'm elevated, I can access the users library folders with impunity.

Comment: Cheers for that - I'd originally shied away from running elevated, but in the circumstances this seems foolish. Having run elevated however, I can do away with the whole zip file altogether and just write the images directly into a folder the users My Pictures folder.